# How to store a reference to a MongoDB connection in a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, nosql

I have a bit of an issue with the asynchronous implementation of the MongoDB driver for Node.js.

In the documentation examples, connection takes place as follows:

```js
const client = new MongoClient(uri, ...);

async function run() {

  try {
    await client.connect();
    const coll = client.db('locations').collection('streets');
    
    coll.find({...});
    
  } catch {
  
    ...
    
  } finally {
  
    client.close();
    
  }
  
}

run().catch(console.dir);
```

But let's say I want to use the connection in an object rather than create a function for every case when I need the connection. For example, I want to create an object which would allow me to insert comments into a database:

```js
const Comments = {
  connection: /* how would I put a MongoDB connection here when it's async? */,
  commentsCollectionRef: /* how would I put a collection reference here? */
  add: function(user, comment) {
          collectionRef.insertOne({user, comment});
  }
};

/* And to use the object like this to insert comments: */
Comment.add("Martin", "hello");
Comment.add("Julie", "hi");
Comment.add("Mary", "hello");
```

Presumably, it is impossible to do something like this:

```js
async function connect() {

  await client.connect();
  
}

const Comments = {

  connection: connect() /* this returns a promise, but you can't store a reference to its value like this */
  
  ...
}
```

Is having a function which connects each time and closes the connection each time really the only option with MongoDB?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to open a new connection every time you call the database. You can simply keep a separate variable with the status of the connection.
Something like:

```js
const client = new MongoClient(uri, ...);
let connected = false;

async function connnect() {
  if(!connected) {
    await client.connect();
    connected = true;
  }
}

async function disconnect() {
  if(connected) {
    await client.close();
    connected = false;
  }
}

// All other comment specific code next...
```

Then you can build your library around this.
For each of your methods that interact with the database, call connect first.
Or simply call `connect` when you boot up the app and `disconnect` when you exit.

However, if you're going to have objects that represent database collections I would recommend having a look at [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/). You can easily define models and it can make your life a bit easier.